# Change color of folded text in Sublime

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any way to change color of the folded text in Sublime. Default color is yellowish.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this color is defined in the color scheme. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using custom one, but could not find the code for folded text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your `.sublime-color-scheme` file, go down to the `"globals"` dict, and add something like

```json
"fold_marker": "#06FF05",
```

which will make it bright green. Obviously, feel free to select your own color.

All of the `globals` options are in [the color scheme documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html) under [Global Settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html#global_settings).